Cannot find django module
I'm watching a tutorial in Django, on my end I created a virtual environment but the Python file can't seem to find the Django modules. Steps I did:

open folder Django
created virtual environment djangocrudenv
activated the environment then pip installed the requirements.txt

then followed the tutorial but as you can see in the attached picture it can't find the Django module
UPDATE: deleted the virtual environment and created another one then ran py manage.py runserver and I can see the page where it says install worked successfully but I still have the missing module warning in the Python file, does that mean it works even with the warning?



Check If you have installed the Django package or not. You can install the Django Package by pip install django If yes, then Check whether you have activated the correct environment or not.

@ManojKamble i have already activated as you can see in the pic, also in the terminal used the python repl and i typed import django then print(django.get_version()) and it showed me the correct version

@NikunjBavaliya already did as you can see in last pic

try to install and use python auto env vscode extension WolfiesHorizon.python-auto-venv. maybe it can find the environment for the terminal but not for the vscode editor

@NikunjBavaliya added update on post above, does that mean it works even with the warning?

SOLVED: i clicked the bottom of the VSCode window to select the python interpreter and it showed the list in the pic below, i selected the recommended interpreter with where it shows Python 3.12.2 ('.venv':venv) and the warning has now dissappeared, so when i created the virtual environment and created the django project folder it somehow automatically chose the interpreter with the Python 3.12.2 Global label, i'm curious why though.


because you didn't select virtual environment for interpreter.
if you wanna fix it follow these steps:

open your editor and click on control+shift+P or go to view and click on command palette
in command palette search select interpreter then click on enter interpreter path
go to your virtual environment path and go to /Scripts folder then select python application

